# android inSampleSize of BitmapFactory.Options()

Tags: android, bitmap, compression

When I tried to compress the size(width & height) of the picture, I have a question about the `inSampleSize` property of `BitmapFactory.Options()`. when `inSampleSize` value is 1, the result is not compressed, when `inSampleSize` value of 2, image compression half, when `inSampleSize` value of 3, image compression half also, when `inSampleSize` value of 4 image compression of 1/4, when `inSampleSize` value of 6, the compression effect is equivalent to `inSampleSize = 4`, when `inSampleSize` is 8, image compression 1/8. so, I come to the preliminary conclusion : does the comopression only take effect when `inSampleSize` value must be 2^n?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from Javadocs in Android source code

> Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other
>   value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

Comment: first, thx for your reply.But if I calculated inSampleSize value of 6, I have to adjust it to  8 to meet the final size requirements,Is there a way to compress pictures according to inSampleSize value of 6?

Comment: @dd101110 The API document is clear, that, you can't.